# Get regular array from Julia Permutations package

Tags: julia

I am using the [Permutations](https://juliaobserver.com/packages/Permutations) package to compute the inverse permutations of a long list of inputs. The following code yields *almost* what I want:

```
using Permutations

students = [[3 4 2 1]
[3 4 1 2]
[4 3 2 1]]

students_inv = [Permutation(i)'.data' for i in eachrow(students)]
```

Then calling `students` yields

```
3×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  4  2  1
 3  4  1  2
 4  3  2  1
```

and calling `students_inv` yields

```
3-element Array{LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,1}},1}:
 [4 3 1 2]
 [3 4 1 2]
 [4 3 2 1]
```

I just want a 3x4 array of integers without all the LinearAlgebra stuff. How can I force Permutations to give me the simpler output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `mapslices`, and `invperm`:

```
julia> students = [ 3  4  2  1
                    3  4  1  2
                    4  3  2  1 ];

julia> mapslices(invperm, students, dims=2)
3×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  3  1  2
 3  4  1  2
 4  3  2  1

julia> using Permutations

julia> mapslices(row -> Permutation(row)'.data, students; dims=2)
3×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  3  1  2
 3  4  1  2
 4  3  2  1
```

Notice that to enter a literal matrix, you can just use spaces and newlines (or semicolons), without first constructing rows separately.

Note also that it might be more natural to work with columns not rows. And that `mapslices` is, unfortunately, slow on large arrays. It can be avoided like this, or you might prefer to work with a vector of vectors (or a vector of tuples) the whole way through, depending on what else you are doing.

```
julia> reduce(hcat, map(invperm, eachcol(permutedims(students))))
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  3  4
 3  4  3
 1  1  2
 2  2  1
```

Comment: There's a builtin! Brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vcat` function

```
julia> students_inv = vcat((Permutation(i)'.data' for i in eachrow(students))...)
3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 4  3  1  2
 3  4  1  2
 4  3  2  1
```

Take a notion, that the generator `()` notation was used instead of list comprehension `[]`.

With that said, it is more efficient to use the column version, since Julia is column major

```
julia> students = [[3, 4, 2, 1] [3, 4, 1, 2] [4, 3, 2, 1]]
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 3  3  4
 4  4  3
 2  1  2
 1  2  1

julia> students_inv = hcat((Permutation(i).data for i in eachcol(students))...)
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 3  3  4
 4  4  3
 2  1  2
 1  2  1
```

```
@btime vcat((Permutation(i)'.data' for i in eachrow($students))...)
#  1.102 μs (26 allocations: 2.31 KiB)

@btime hcat((Permutation(i).data for i in eachcol($students))...)
# 699.378 ns (15 allocations: 1.31 KiB)
```